# Vertical spaces between lines in cases environment

Tags: math-mode, cases

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  X_i = 
  \begin{cases}
    \left[\begin{smallmatrix}
      0 \\ 1 \\ 2
    \end{smallmatrix}\right]
    &
    \text{if $i$ is even;}
    \\
    \left[\begin{smallmatrix}
      2 \\ 1 \\ 0
    \end{smallmatrix}\right]
    &
    \text{otherwise.}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

This is the LaTeX code that I wrote based on a `cases` environment. There's no space between the matrices on the right. What's the best way to add some vertical spaces to separate them?

[image]

p.s. This is a simplified form of my original writing, so I cannot just accept suggestions like 'use a matrix transpose to transform the column vector into a row vector.'

Comment: I'll leave my answer, but as I see that this is a fairly clear duplicate I'll also vote to close.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the optional argument to `\\` to add additional space between the lines, e.g.`\\[10pt]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  X_i = 
  \begin{cases}
    \left[\begin{smallmatrix}
      0 \\ 1 \\ 2
    \end{smallmatrix}\right]
    &
    \text{if $i$ is even;}
    \\[10pt]
    \left[\begin{smallmatrix}
      2 \\ 1 \\ 0
    \end{smallmatrix}\right]
    &
    \text{otherwise.}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Or you can load the `mathtools` package (which loads and extends `amsmath`) and its `dcases` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  X_i = 
  \begin{dcases}
    \left[\begin{smallmatrix}
      0 \\ 1 \\ 2
    \end{smallmatrix}\right]
    &
    \text{if $i$ is even;}
    \\
    \left[\begin{smallmatrix}
      2 \\ 1 \\ 0
    \end{smallmatrix}\right]
    &
    \text{otherwise.}
  \end{dcases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```